# Issue in XML to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to do XML to XML by removing some nodes. I am new to XSLt and it is confusing.

XML input,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <role>
       <status>success</status>
       <data>
          <name>ac1</name>
       </data>
       <data>
          <name>ac2</name>
       </data>
       <data>
          <name>ac3</name>
       </data>
       <day>monday</day>
    </role>
```

XSLT is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="role">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <disaply_name>
               <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </disaply_name>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<role>
  <disaply_name>ac1</disaply_name>
  <disaply_name>ac2</disaply_name>
  <disaply_name>ac3</disaply_name>
</role>
```

Expected Output is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<role2>
  <disaply_name>ac1</disaply_name>
</role2>
<role2>
  <disaply_name>ac2</disaply_name>
</role2>
<role2>
  <disaply_name>ac3</disaply_name>
</role2>
</root>
```

What should I modify? .......................

Comment: You should modify what your expected output is. You shouldn't be having several `<role>` tags, as it is a root node. Your expected output is not valid XML.

Comment: I have changed the expected output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `<xsl:copy>` means that it's copying the current node, in this case `<role>`, which explains its appearance in your output. And since there are no other nodes specified before, XSLT is considering it to be the root node. So I just removed it, and correctly placed the nodes `<root>` and `<role2>`.

To got your expected output, try using the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="role">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="data">
                <role2>
                    <display_name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                    </display_name>
                </role2>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <role2>
    <display_name>ac1</display_name>
  </role2>
  <role2>
    <display_name>ac2</display_name>
  </role2>
  <role2>
    <display_name>ac3</display_name>
  </role2>
</root>
```